# How to put two ng-grids in one line

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm trying to put multiple ng-grids in one line.

But not sure about how to do this, anyone helps?

http://plnkr.co/edit/tQJNpB?p=preview

Comment: Confused...you mean you want the two grids to be next to each other each taking up half of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align:top" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align:top" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptiontest"></div>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SQYScP?p=preview)